# Python campo total

Tags: python, django

Tengo el siguiente código:

**forms.py:**

```
MAX_DETALLES = 5

Detalle_VentaFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    Venta, 
    Detalle_Venta, 
    fields=('cantidad','producto'),
    #SI AGREGO EN FIELDS SUBTOTAL, NO ME DEJA MOSTRAR EL FORM DIRECTAMENTE
    #readonly_fields = ('subtotal',),
    can_delete= True,
    extra= MAX_DETALLES

)
class VentaForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Venta
        fields=('cliente', 'fecha','descripcion', 'descuento', 'total')
        #inlines = (Detalle_VentaForm,)
        #exclude=('',)
```

**Models.py:**

```
# Venta es subclase de Operacion
class Venta(Operacion):

        cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente, verbose_name= _("cliente"))

        class Meta:
                verbose_name = _('Venta')
                #ordering = ["monto"]
        def __unicode__(self):
                return unicode(self.fecha)


class Detalle_Venta(models.Model):
    venta = models.ForeignKey(Venta)
    cantidad = models.IntegerField(default= 1)
    producto = models.ForeignKey(Producto)

    def _get_subtotal(self):
        return self.cantidad*self.producto.precio

    subtotal = property(_get_subtotal)

    def _get_total(self):
        venta.total = venta.total+self.subtotal
        return venta.total
    venta.total = property(_get_total)
    class Meta:
                verbose_name = _('Detalle')
                #ordering = ["monto"]
    def __unicode__(self):
            return unicode(self.producto)
```

No muestra el subtotal, no me deja agregarlo al fields del form inline
Como hacer para que sume total?

Comment: Agrega el codigo directamente en tu pregunta utilizando {} ya que asi la calidad de tu pregunta es muy baja.

Comment: ¡Hola Rut, bienvenida a Stack Overflow! Como dice @MaxSandoval, mejor pon el código directamente en la pregunta para que se vea mejor.

Comment: ¿Por qué dices que no te deja mostrar?, ¿te arroja algún error? Mientras más detalles, mejor.